# Elimination Method Confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

really basic algebra question which nonetheless has me stumped.

First, some background:

We have constants $a, b, c,$ and $d$ such that $ad-bc \ne 0$. I've been tasked to solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of the constants above. It is a system of linear equations:

$ax + by = 1$,
$cx + dy = 2$.

I decided to solve for y first, multiplied each equation by a suitable number to have the same coefficients for $x$ in each equation, subtracted the 2nd equation from the first and obtained the following: $\frac {c-2a}{bc-ad}$. However, according to solutions the proper answer would be $\frac {2a-c}{ad-bc}$. According to the author, he went about obtaining the value for $y$ by subtracting the **1st equation from the second (unsure why?)** after getting the same coeffs. for $x$. For some reason it's not clicking. Would these two answers for $y$ be equivalent? Why or why not?

Comment: You just have a negative in the numerator and the denominator.  They're the same.

Comment: If you multiply one of those fractions by $\frac{-1}{-1}$, it turns into the other. They're equivalent.

Comment: Can either elaborate? I'm still not getting it for whatever reason.

Comment: $\dfrac{c-2a}{bc-ad}=\dfrac{(-1)\cdot(-c+2a)}{(-1)\cdot(-bc+ad)}=\dfrac{-c+2a}{-bc+ad}=\dfrac{2a-c}{ad-bc}$